# Inconsistent crash bug in C++ program

Tags: c++, string

*In case this is relevant I am not compiling this under a Linux environment, instead I am using the tdm-gcc compiler.*

I am writing a textbox for a game and I would like split the words that are being spoken into seperate words to do work on them later. My issue is that the split function that I wrote works in the constructor but not in the advance text method.

This is the split function:

```
char** split(char* string, const char* delimeter)
{
    char** arr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*((strlen(string)+1)/2+1));
    char* token = strtok(string, delimeter);
    int i = 0;

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        arr[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
        strcpy(arr[i], token);
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, delimeter);
    }
    arr[i] = NULL;
    return arr;
}
```

This is my (unfinished) textbox class

```
class Textbox
{
    ...
    public:
        Textbox(char* data[], int numSentences, SDL_Renderer* renderer, int scale)
        {
            ...
            fp = fopen("./text/names/female/femalenames1.txt", "r");

            char* buffer;
            int numBytes;

            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
            numBytes = ftell(fp);
            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
            buffer = (char*)calloc(numBytes, sizeof(char));
            fread(buffer, sizeof(char), numBytes, fp);
            fclose(fp);

            char** array = split(buffer, " ");

            free(buffer);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        void advanceText()
        {
            this->textPosition++;
            char** array = split(this->data[this->textPosition], " ");
        }
        bool hasNext()
        {
            return data[textPosition] == "END" ? false:true;
        }
};
```

Context of advanceText():

```
int playerIntro()
{
    bool running = true;
    ...
    SDL_Event event;
    const char* dialogue[] = {"1st thing", "2nd thing", "3rd thing", "END"};
    Textbox text((char**)dialogue, 50, renderer, scale);
    while (running)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RETURN and text.hasNext())
            {
                text.advanceText();
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

It seems the problem is actually in the first strtok function of the split function

Please note that any undefined variables in this post are actually defined in source code. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Many of your issues will go away when you switch to `std::string` for text, `std::vector` for arrays and pass by reference.

Comment: Any reason you are not using C++ features such as `std::ifstream`, `operator new` and smart pointers?

Comment: Lastly, you don't need to use the `this->` syntax; only use to differentiate parameter names from member names (I suggest making them different).

Comment: Where's the definition of `split` function?  I didn't find it in the online references.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews With this program I must use only C features besides classes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My apologies, I removed it. I am going to add it back to the question. I wrote it myself.

Comment: What you have posted is even less of an [mcve] than your original version.  Not only do you need to put the definition of `split` back, but you need to show the context in which `advanceText` is being called.

Comment: Since you are using C functions and C-style strings, consider using `strtok` rather than re-inventing the wheel.  Also remember about that terminating nul character.

Comment: What is it that you intend this line to accomplish: `char** arr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*((strlen(string)+1)/2+1));`? It appears to be allocating one `char*` for every 2 characters in the input string. Is that intentional?